# Is it possible to do effectively irrational-interval sampling of a continuous signal?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Suppose there is a real-valued $f(t)$, with $t$ being time. And one wishes to sample at interval of $\pi$, for example.

Perfect irrational-interval sampling is not possible, but is there a way to do irrational-interval sampling so that errors incurred do not accumulate over time and remain small?

Comment: What are your constraints? Is the function being sampled by hardware, or by software? If hardware, what kind of hardware?

Comment: Software, of course. Constraints are only about error magnitude at every time $t$ under some specified $k$.

Comment: Any arithmetic unit is limited to rational numbers, so how many bits you use will determine how accurate you will be. If you use `long double`, then you'll be able to get a 18 digits (I think). Maybe you can figure how much smaller you're approximation is than the irrational number and bounce back and forth between your step size being a little bit less than and then a little bit greater than.